# ffmpeg resample to flac loud clicks/noise

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flac

I'm using ffmpeg to resample a DSD file to Flac & mp3. I don't experience any problems with the mp3 resample, but with the flac resample there is always a loud click at the end of a track, as seen on this image:

[image: Wave form as displayed in Audacity]

I'm using a basic command in command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.dsf -ar 192000 -acodec flac output.flac
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x7fe617809000] Changeing bps to 8
[dsf @ 0x7fe617000000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, dsf, from 'input.dsf':
  Metadata:
    title           : Bach Brandenburg no. 6 - Allegro
    artist          : Florilegium
    album           : Brandenburg Concertos
    track           : 3
    Tool Version    : 18.0.212
    genre           : Classical
    composer        : Bach
    Catalog #       : 35914
    Format          : DSD
    ISRC            : NLA460912792
    Label           : Channel Classics
    Tool Name       : Media Center
    date            : 2014
  Duration: 00:06:00.31, bitrate: 5644 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: dsd_lsbf_planar, 352800 Hz, stereo, fltp, 5644 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1429x1417 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1429:1417], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Picture
      comment         : Cover (front)
[flac @ 0x7fe617122000] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
Output #0, flac, to 'output.flac':
  Metadata:
    title           : Bach Brandenburg no. 6 - Allegro
    artist          : Florilegium
    album           : Brandenburg Concertos
    TRACKNUMBER     : 3
    Tool Version    : 18.0.212
    genre           : Classical
    composer        : Bach
    Catalog #       : 35914
    Format          : DSD
    ISRC            : NLA460912792
    Label           : Channel Classics
    Tool Name       : Media Center
    date            : 2014
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 192000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 flac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dsd_lsbf_planar (native) -> flac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=  306541kB time=00:05:58.10 bitrate=7012.3kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:306532kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.002733%
```

Comment: Please provide the full, uncut command line output.

Comment: Hi @slhck, just added the output. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try again with a more recent version, e.g. by upgrading your Homebrew build, or by using a static build from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html — yours is already a little outdated.

Comment: Hi @slhck, unfortunately I'm also experiencing clicks with the latest (develop) version (ffmpeg version N-85769-gc53bf8c)

`ffmpeg version N-85769-gc53bf8c Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree --disable-static --enable-shared`

Comment: Does same happens without resampling?

Comment: Jip, also when I'm encoding to .wav, I think it has something to do with the DSD lib?

Comment: Did some more research, the click appear when a DSD is '**dsd_lsbf_planar**' and not when '**dsd_msbf**'

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `-ar 192000` to `-ar 176400`.

I have encountered this too when I play `dsf` with `ffmpeg` in my iPhone. When I set my output sample rate (aka: the resample rate) to 48000, I got the click noise at the end of audio, but when I change the output sample rate to 44100, everything is fine. I think this is because the resample thing, because `dsd`'s sample rate is measured by 44100, such as `dsd64` is 64* 44100.

Just a thought, not proved yet!